# connect a cisco router to the internet through a cable modem

Tags: cisco, routing, dns

The router gets an External IP address via DHCP from the Cable modem
Clients inside the network get an IP address from Router's DHCP server
I can ping that the external IP address from a client inside my network
I cannot ping `8.8.8.8`. Did a traceroute and ping dies at router's internal IP (GigabitEthernet0/1)

I think the issue might be at the NAT configuration, any ideas are very welcome!

This is my config:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.25

ip dhcp pool 10
 network 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.0.0.1
 dns-server 10.0.0.1

interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 duplex auto
 speed auto

ip classless
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0

ip nat inside source list LAN interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
!
ip access-list standard LAN
 permit 10.0.0.0 0.0.255.255
!
ip access-list extended WAN
 permit tcp any any established
 permit ip any any
```

Comment: Hello, Dario, and welcome to Network Engineering! I would consider removing default route and adding to your GigabitEthernet 0/0 line `ip dhcp client request router` that will request default route from your ISP.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Andrey, I will try that tonight

Comment: I looked on the commend list for the interface and I cannot find "ip dhcp client request router" can you please be more specific with the command and where to add it? thank you

Comment: It may be that it is actually working, but your DNS is not right. It is pointing to your router instead of a DNS server. In the DHCP configuration, you have `dns-server 10.0.0.1`. Try it with a real DNS server like `dns-server 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: That's a good point, I had an DNS error from the client when I ran the windows troubleshooter

Comment: Changed the DNS config at the pool from 10.0.0.1 to 8.8.8.8
Removed the ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 g0/0 line
Same error
What is weird is with the Cisco RT I get a 76.xx.xx.xx external IP and with the home router I get an 24.XX.XX.XX address....

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I thought I did. If not let me know how to do it, thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the router is getting DHCP from your ISP, consider changing your route to

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
```

You do have to delete the existing route

```
no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
```

Your access-list WAN isn't doing anything: it's good practice to delete ones which you're not using.  Additionally, your access-list LAN is a /16 but your address on the local side is /24 -- not necessarily an error

Once you have connectivity to 8.8.8.8, you might want to change the DNS server address handed out by your DHCP.

Comment: Thank you, I will update after changes are tested and completed.

Comment: I tried to test the change on packet trace and I'm getting this error:

1921(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp 
                                                             ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Comment: I see that packet tracer is showing routers running various version of IOS; the command is working on my physical routers running Version 15.4(3)M3.  What model and version of router do you have?

Comment: That's a good point! the Router is a 1921 running 15.1

Comment: Per ricky's answer, you'll get a route from DHCP without explicitly asking for it, just tested now with packet tracer on 2811 with 12.2: `interface fast0/0 ip address dhcp` and no route statements at all.  `show ip route` shows a default route as given by dhcp

Comment: added this route ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
deleted no ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0
still not working
Added the outside address to the interface manually
nothing
Enter in the modem config and I found that the modem added the RT MAC address dynamically to the table

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0`. Do you know what proxy-arp is? Do you *need* proxy-arp? I didn't think so.

You don't need to set a default route as dhcp will automatically set it.

In 99% of all "can't get to the internet" problems it is later revealed ip routing wasn't enabled. (or more accurately, someone *explicitly* turned it off, as it's on by default) Is there, perhaps, a `no ip routing` line in your config?

Comment: I checked in my notes and is not but, I will verify that in the main config at the Router later, thank you

Comment: Update: if you have "backup" default routes (higher metric), the dhcp route will have to be explicitly included. Wasn't necessary prior to IOS 15.

Comment: The last step for making all this work was simply to restart the Modem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out for me after I changed the ACL from:

permit 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255

to:

Permit any

Answer (score 0):

Yes some changes definitely required on Default routing and access -list configuration .

**Default routing**

IP route   0.0.0.0 0.0 .0.0 ethernet 0/0

**Access -list**

#access-list standard LAN
permit IP 10.0.0.0 0.0.255.255 Any